All http requests fail when using API level 25 or lower
Since approximatively a week, our Android application won't connect to our backend anymore. All http requests raise this error:

In this example I'm just running a url tester on a ngrok server but any url have the same result.
It only happens on emulators and devices with API level of 25 or lower. The problem is that we use humanoid robots so we cannot upgrade their API level.
Do you know if anything changed recently that could have caused this?
I tried every API levels and it started working at this API level:

